# C# Convert.FromBase64String retorna diferente de PHP base64_decode

Tags: php, c#, base64

Estou fazendo o decode em c# de um base64 para poder gerar um Qrcode, em PHP funciona normal mas, em c# o retorno do decode fica diferente. Este base64 é criado e criptografado pela Serpro e eles pedem para fazer o decode do base64 e com o byte[] que retorna do decode gerar um Qrcode.
Código PHP funcionando normal:

```
<?php  
include('C:\php\lib\phpqrcode\qrlib.php');
    $file = 'D:\Teste\qrcode.png';
    $a = base64_decode('X0gJQwUAEQBGMEQCIFFztpz6Yi2OHOR9QafHjL4y8MtlwHG7fgE9q9KycCBXAiBlU+xqMnYHBdpArpgxZee/PvsqO5BmEyvAdqSFtLzCNgAAAAxJBBhFVBJBlhBVlAA=');
    QRcode::png($a, $file,  QR_ECLEVEL_M, 3, 1);
?>
```

Em php retorna este Qrcode correto, validado pela Serpro!

[image: Em php retorna este Qrcode correto!]

Código em c# com o decode diferente

```
// Dll MessagingToolkit.QRCode
string stringBase64Endode = "X0gJQwUAEQBGMEQCIFFztpz6Yi2OHOR9QafHjL4y8MtlwHG7fgE9q9KycCBXAiBlU+xqMnYHBdpArpgxZee/PvsqO5BmEyvAdqSFtLzCNgAAAAxJBBhFVBJBlhBVlAA=";
string textoDecode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(stringBase64Endode));

var qrCode = new QRCodeEncoder();
qrCode.QRCodeBackgroundColor = Color.White;
qrCode.QRCodeForegroundColor = Color.Black;
qrCode.QRCodeEncodeMode = QRCodeEncoder.ENCODE_MODE.BYTE;
qrCode.QRCodeErrorCorrect = QRCodeEncoder.ERROR_CORRECTION.Q;
qrCode.QRCodeScale = 2;
var resultado = qrCode.Encode(textoDecode);
resultado.Save("D:\Teste\qrcode.png");
```

Em c# retorna este Qrcode incorreto, Não validado pela Serpro!

[image: Em c# retorna este Qrcode incorreto]

Como faço para que o Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String()) em c# retorne o mesmo resultado que o base64_decode em php?

Comment: Não entendi... a sua string já está em base64, por que você precisa do UTF8 no decode?

Comment: Olá Leandro, eu uso UTF8 porque o `Convert.FromBase64String` retorna um byte[] e a dll que gera o qrcode `var resultado = qrCode.Encode(textoDecode);` recebe um texto. Existe outra maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Que string ele espera? Se o tipo que foi encodado não for texto não tem mágica não...

Comment: @LeandroAngelo: Todas dll que conheço em c# que gera qrcode recebe um texto, em php eu posso jogar direto o retorno do `base64_decode` pra gerar qrcode mas, em c# não sei como fazer.

Comment: você já experimentou olhar se esse seu base64 já não é o png com o QR code? Você sabe como um QR funciona, como é composto e que tipo de informação ele armazena?

Comment: Tipo, qual é a info que esse QR deve armazenar?

Comment: Já pensei nisso e tentei usar:`using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Bytes))
            {
                return Image.FromStream(ms);
            }`
e da erro: Parâmetro inválido.

Comment: Esse qrcode vai em placa de carro, a Serpro gera o base64 com uma string criptografada, essa string criptografada deve ir no qrcode. O processo que eles pedem é fazer o decode do base64 e o resultado colocar no qrcode.

Comment: e como você pretende descriptografar? O que de fato vc está tentando fazer, ler ou gerar um QR? Ou a questão é que de fato se você gerar dois QR, um com a biloteca do PHP e outro com essa no C#, a aparência da imagem é diferente?

Comment: Estou tentando gerar o qrcode e não posso descriptografar, apenas tenho que fazer decode no base64 e com o resultado criar o qrcode do jeito que mostrei em php que funciona normalmente. A aparência entre os dois qrcode é bem diferente.

Comment: Então... é isso que eu estou tentando dizer... você não tem que decodar aquela string inicial, você tem que gerar usando ela. Afinal... ela vem como byte ou como string?

Comment: Tem algum exemplo?

Comment: Que biblioteca você está utilizando?

Comment: Estou usando a MessagingToolkit.QRCode e já tentei com a ZXing.Net, nehuma dá o resultado do que usei em php.

Comment: O resultado é um QR code idêntico? Você sabe que isso não é necessário e o que importa é o resultado da leitura... A aparência vai mudar por diversos parâmetros, como pontos de correção, tolerância a erro e etc... Dificilmente duas bibliotecas diferentes vão gerar exatamente igual, à menos que você configure exatemente tudo igual e que elas compartilhem o mesmo algoritmo para a geração...

Comment: É que o exemplo em php retorna o qrcode correto que pode ser validado pela serpro, já no c# com essas duas dll retorna um qrcode diferente e que não valida pela serpro.

Comment: inclua os QR codes gerados na sua pergunta e a especificação da Serpro para os requisitos de validação

Comment: Fiz  edição da pergunta.

Comment: Camarada, só por desencargo, tente com essa lib aqui
https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder

Comment: @MárcioCristian: Com a dll QRCoder também não funcionou, acredito que o problema esteva na maneira que o FromBase64 do C# trabalha.